# If $A,H\in GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$, What happen for $H A H^{-1}$, if $h(i,j)\longrightarrow‎ 0$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

If $A$ and $H$ is a two $n\times n$ matrixs, such that $\det(A)\neq 0$ and $ \det(H)\neq 0$, what happen for $H A H^{-1}$, if $h(i,j)‎\longrightarrow‎ 0 $?
Is $H A H^{-1}‎\cong A$?$ \ \  \ (1\leq i,j\leq n).$
Any idea can be helpful.thanks

Comment: What is the meaning of $\simeq$?

Comment: Does $\cong$ mean that they are congruent or asymptotically equivalent? What do you mean by $h(i,j) \rightarrow 0$ - that there is a sequence of $H$'s whose components tend to zero?

Comment: What is $h(i, j)$?

Answer (score 3):

This is a wrong question because the limit of $HAH^{-1}$ in general may not exist. The right question should be: provided that $\lim_{H\to 0}HAH^{-1}$ exists, is it necessarily similar to $A$?

The answer, unfortunately, is no. Here is a counterexample:
$$
HAH^{-1}
= \pmatrix{x^2&0\\ 0&x}
\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}
\pmatrix{\frac1{x^2}&0\\ 0&\frac1x}
= \pmatrix{1&x\\ 0&1}.
$$

If you mean that a certain entry of $H$ approaches to zero while the others are kept constant, the answer is still no. We only need to modify the above counterexample by a little bit:
$$
HAH^{-1}
= \pmatrix{x&0\\ 0&1}
\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}
\pmatrix{\frac1x&0\\ 0&1}
= \pmatrix{1&x\\ 0&1}.
$$

**Edit.** Note that the $A$ above is not diagonalisable. In general, [the similarity orbit of a real or complex matrix $A$ is closed if and only if $A$ is diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563174/for-which-matrices-a-in-mathscrm-n-mathbb-c-is-the-similarity-class-of).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $h(i,j)$ denotes the coefficients of $H$.

In the case $n=1$ the product $HAH^{-1}$ is a product of numbers, in which $H$ converges to $0$. Then obviously the product converges to $A$.

In the case $n>1$ one first observes, that matrix multiplication is a continous operation considering for example the euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (or any $p$-metric, $p\in\mathbb{N}\cup\infty$). Convergence with respect to that metric is the same as coefficient-wise concergence.

By the theorem of Cayley-Hamilton $H^n+a_{n-1}H^{n-1}+\ldots +a_0=0$ for some real numbers $a_k$, where $a_0\neq 0$ by assumption (up to sign $a_0$ is the determinant of $H$). Hence

$H^{-1}=-\frac{1}{a_0}(H^{n-1}+a_{n-1}H^{n-2}+\ldots +a_1)$.

Consequently

$\begin{array}{rcl}\lim_{H\rightarrow 0}(HAH^{-1})&=&(\lim_{H\rightarrow 0}H)A(\lim_{H\rightarrow 0}-\frac{1}{a_0}(H^{n-1}+a_{n-1}H^{n-2}+\ldots +a_1))\\
&=&0\;A\;(-\frac{a_1}{a_0}E)=0,
\end{array}$

where $E$ is the unit matrix.

Comment: that can't be right. Take $A = I$, the identity, $H=hI$ for some scalar $h\ne 0$. Then, $HAH^{-1} = I$.

Comment: This isn't right. One can construct a counterexample where some of the elements of $HAH^{-1}$ diverge.

Comment: @ Hagen Knaf . What a beautiful mistake ! Your limit $-a_1/a_0 I_n$ varies because it depends on $a_0,a_1$ that both tend to $0$. I think it's better that  you remove your answer.